# Unity C#: How to send messages from one application to another on different IP?

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, networking, tcp

I need a simple code which would demonstrate sending a message, say "HI" to another unity exe build.

something of this sort:

---Application 1 at IP address 192.168.0.10:

```
    void sendMessage(string ClientIP)
 {
       string Message = "Hi";
       //code to send message to 192.168.0.11 (ClientIP)

 }
```

---Application 2 at IP address 192.168.0.11:

```
    void Update()
 {
       //Check for messages
       if (received)
       {
             OnReceiveMessage(message);
       }

 }
 void OnReceiveMessage(string message)
 {
       string MessageReceived = message;
       Debug.Log(message);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The unity documentation on networking can be found [enter link description here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetClientServer.html)

The following three functions, sum it up:

```
    // Create a server and listen on a port
    public void SetupServer()
    {
        NetworkServer.Listen(4444);
        isAtStartup = false;
    }

    // Create a client and connect to the server port
    public void SetupClient()
    {
        myClient = new NetworkClient();
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);     
        myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);
        isAtStartup = false;
    }

    // Create a local client and connect to the local server
    public void SetupLocalClient()
    {
        myClient = ClientScene.ConnectLocalServer();
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);     
        isAtStartup = false;
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not working. This would have been perfect but it was for UNET which is deprecated and I could not find a workaround for this in mirror.